# cURL via PHP page

Tags: php, curl, centos8

I'm trying to do a curl request via PHP. When i do this request on the server shell directly.

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

My PHP code is below,

```
<?php

echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa") . "</br>";

$url = "http://www.google.com";

$handle = curl_init();
// Set the url
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set the result output to be a string.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($handle);
print_r(curl_getinfo($handle));
echo "</br>";
echo curl_errno($handle);
echo "</br>";
if(curl_errno($handle)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}

curl_close($handle);

echo "</br> fin";
?>
```

When I load the page, i get the following:

```
    Array ( [url] => http://www.google.com/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.029675 [namelookup_time] => 0.038741 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => [appconnect_time_us] => 0 [connect_time_us] => 0 [namelookup_time_us] => 38741 [pretransfer_time_us] => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 [total_time_us] => 29675 )
    7
    Curl error:
    fin
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as i'm not getting the correct download to what I would expect with the curl command (would expect to get the HTML download from the page?). I was testing this with an API but have simplified it to try and diagnose.

EDIT: fixed code and explained the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with what you are doing? You need to ask your question more clearly.

Comment: Why do you have curl_init twice?